# Python restful API tools selection when DB tables already created

Tags: python, database, rest

I used [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to write API, the Django ORM is really conveinent like DB migrate or relation field's query.

But now we have a case, there is a DB with about 30 tables with data in it. And we have to query the DB and write some API. So I think I can't use Django this time.

What develop tools do you recommand to write restful API in Python if your case have the database that already created tables in it?

Comment: You can query the database without using Django's ORM.

Comment: btw which database you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **inspectdb** command to create django models from existing database.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Here is the docs: [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/)